# asymptotic of graph equation

Tags: limits, functions, asymptotics, graphing-functions, infinity

I need help to resolve this exercise :

> Using asymptotic limited development in the neighborhood of + ∞ of the
>   function
>
> $$g(x) = 2x + 3 \sqrt{x^2 -1} $$ Determine an equation of the straight
>   line asymptote to the graph of g in + ∞ and position the
>   representative curve of g with respect to this asymptote.

Sorry for my basic english..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is asking: What does this graph look like for very large $x$?

$$
g(x) = 2x + 3 \sqrt{x^2 -1} \stackrel{\text{subtracting 1 is no biggie for}\;x\sim \infty}{\sim} 2x+3\sqrt{x^2}\\
=2x+3|x|\stackrel{x>0}{=}5x\Rightarrow g(x)\sim 5x
$$
or the graph of the function approaches the graph of $y=5x$.

edit: As noted, in my attempt to be cute I may have swept something important under the rug, if instead we had 
$$
g(x)=2x + 3 \sqrt{x^2 -x}
$$
This function would be similar to $5x+b$, since the lower order term in the square root is still dominated, but will add a relatively small but existent perturbation for large $x$.

Comment: Had that $1$ inside that radical been an $x$, then subtracting $x$ from $x^2$ also would not have been an issue for $x$ going to infinity, yet, the equation of the asymptote would be different. While I won't downvote, I think the reasoning is flawed...

Comment: @imranfat had that 1 been an x, then it definitely would be a "biggie" for $x\sim \infty$.

Comment: +1 for "no biggie". @imranfat: I agree, but I think that's fixed with a sentence of elaboration.

Comment: @qbert. That is where the reasoning fails. Had that $1$ been an $x$, the equation of the asymptote would have been $y=5x+b$ with a nonzero $b$. Your argument only works if behind the $x^2$ is a constant, like $-1$ and I think you should point that out in the answer...

Comment: @imranfat fair enough. I have only ever cared about the function it looks like up to a translation

Comment: @qbert True, the asymptote is shifted. (b-value)

Answer (score 0):

the asymptotic will have the form $y=ax+b$

$a= g'(x)\lim_{x\to∞ } =\lim_{x\to∞ }$$2+$ $\frac{3x}{\sqrt {x^2-1}}\ $ =

$ \lim_{x\to∞ }$$2+$ $\frac{3x}{x\sqrt {1-\frac{1}{x^2}}}\ $ = $ \lim_{x\to∞ }$$2+$ $\frac{3}{\sqrt {1-\frac{1}{x^2}}}\ $

$\frac{1}{x^2}$ will be 0 so the limit is

$ \lim_{x\to∞ }$$2+$ $\frac{3}{\sqrt {1}}\ $ $= 2+3$ $=a$

b will be infinity big

So the asymptotic function will be $y=5x$